# Module nammed "crypto" not found

Tags: python

I've been trying to do the website picoCTF "Mind your Ps and Qs" and I can't seem to fix this problem. I've tried installing various libraries but nothing worked!

```
#Decrypt 
from Crypto.Util.number import inverse, long_to_bytes

c = 8533139361076999596208540806559574687666062896040360148742851107661304651861689
n = 769457290801263793712740792519696786147248001937382943813345728685422050738403253
e = 65537

p = 1617549722683965197900599011412144490161
q = 475693130177488446807040098678772442581573

b = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
d = inverse(e, b)

f = pow(c, d, n)

print(f)
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

I'm basically trying to decrypt a RSA key here, but I can't seem to use the module!

Comment: `Crypto` is provided by https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/ ...

Comment: How did you install? How are you running the code? See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

**Use Python3's pycryptodome instead!**

Make sure to uninstall all versions of crypto and pycrypto first, then install pycryptodome:

```
pip3 uninstall crypto 
pip3 uninstall pycrypto 
pip3 install pycryptodome
```

All of these three packages get installed to the same folder, named Crypto. Installing different packages under the same folder name can be a common source for errors!

**Best practice is to use virtual environments**

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct import is as follows:

```
from Cryptodome.Util.number import inverse, long_to_bytes
```